# Linking to specific mail in group conversation in Outlook Online from Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I list mails in group conversation threads through the Graph API.
Would like to create a link to a specific mail in the thread but I can not seem to create a link to the mail in outlook web-app.
I have a way of doing it for mails sent to a "User" via Deeplink https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=.....
But whatever Id I put in that url it will not open the correct thing.
Available from my API-queries are 
Group id
conversation id
What i think is a thread id
& post id

Answer (score 1):

The "[https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#get-a-message)" use message of ews/owa id.
The ids in [Graph Mail API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages) result is encrypted, we cannot pass the ids to "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=" directly.

[You will need to convert from Type HexEntryId to EWSid eg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/convertid-operation).

Although we can find some demo code in the network, but this need many configuration operation, so if you are not familiar with exchagne/EWS, this approach is not recommended. This is not just dev issue but may involve many IT pro issue.